# clone table row, append random or sequential number to ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this code

```
$('input.clone').live('click', function(){
   //put jquery this context into a var
   var $btn = $(this);
   //use .closest() to navigate from the buttno to the closest row and clone it
   var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone();
   //append the cloned row to end of the table

   //clean ids if you need to
   $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function(){
       //clear id or change to something else
       this.id += '_clone';
   });

   //finally append new row to end of table
   $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );
});
```

Problem is, each row i clone gets named whatever _clone
How would i write this so that each time i run the function, it picks either a random or more idealy sequential number to append to the id isntead of "_clone"

Comment: what are the id's to start with? If they can be row_x then it would help

Comment: Well when i pull them from a DB, im going to use php to name them sequential numbers

Comment: Also are you sure it is only the tr's that have id's?

Comment: otherwise this code will start duplicating things

Answer (score 1):

```
String(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000))
```

will give you a random number in string form between 0 and 999999.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the count of rows in the table

```
$clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function(){
       //clear id or change to something else
       var rowCount = $btn.closest('tr').siblings().length;
       this.id += 'row_' + rowCount;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.clone').live('click', function(){
   var $btn = $(this);
   var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone();

   $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function(){
       this.id += '_clone' + $(this).siblings().size();
   });

   //finally append new row to end of table
   $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );
});
```

Comment: same as mine + size() is slower than .length (size() actually calls .length internally)